# Python script to change resolv.conf [Permission issue]

Tags: python, file-io, chmod

Hey everybody, I am just newbie at Python. I wanted to write a script in Python to change DNS.

But I learned that resolv.conf is ***read-only*** file, after writing that code. Because I took that error: **IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/resolv.conf'**

```
myFile= open("/etc/resolv.conf", "w")
```

Then, I made a little search and found `os.chmode()` and I wrote a new line to remove all privileges of ***resolv.conf*** which is:

```
os.chmod("/etc/resolv.conf", 0777)
```

But now I'm taking that error: **IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/resolv.conf'**

I can't get over this question and I'm waiting for your advices.

Thank you.

Comment: It's called **script**, not *scrypt*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/etc/resolv.conf` is typically owned by `root`. Unless your script is run in such a way that it has [root privileges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser), it won't be able to change the file.

Answer (score 0):

Chmod you must run as root before your script. And when you get permissions, your script will run without errors

Answer (score 0):

You should never allow for a file like resolv.conf to be writable by all. It looks like you were chmod'ing  it, or trying to anyway, to 777. That's really bad. There is a lot someone could do by changing a resolver on a host and making that host point to systems that were setup for malicious reasons. For example, one could have their own LDAP server, and by changing resolv.conf point a system at their resolver, and at their LDAP server, thereby possibly gaining privileged levels of access.

Keep this file locked down at all times.